# How to scan multiple text files for information and copy it to a tab-separated file

Tags: perl, csv

Super n00by here trying to get some code to work. I basically have a project where I'm parsing 200 medium-sized text files and need to print the results to another tab-delimited file. I'm trying to extract the *Phone*, *address*, and *zip code*, and print them all on a single line together with the name of the file they came from.

I've succeeded in being able to search for a phone number, but I don't know how to search for the other two strings without wrecking what I've done.

I also have a problem where the file name prints with the phone number that's in it but also with the phone number from the next text file.

Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $calls_dir = "Ask/";
opendir( my $search_dir, $calls_dir ) or die "$!\n";
my @files = grep /\.html$/i, readdir $search_dir;
closedir $search_dir;
print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

my %seen = ();
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $current_file = $calls_dir . $file;
    open my $FILE, '<', $current_file or die "$file: $!\n";

    while (<$FILE>) {
        #if (/phone/i) {
        chomp;

        #if (/phone\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
        #if (/^phone\s*:\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
        if (/Phone:\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
            $seen{$1} = 1;

            foreach my $addr ( sort keys %seen ) {
                print "\n";
                print "\n";
                print $file;
                print "$addr\n";
                print "\n";
                print "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    close $FILE;
}
```

Lines 28 & 29 are where I'm printing now but I really want to print tab delimited to a file and as far as what I'm getting back here's an example with the problem:

```
out_Agilent_Technologies_ask.html+1 408-555-8886. Fax: +1 408-555-8474.
out_Illumina_ask.html+1 408-555-8886. Fax: +1 408-555-8474.
out_Illumina_ask.html408.555.5150
```

The problem is the first number gets printed with the second company name in line 2.  Line 3 print the file name with the phone number that's in it correctly.  Is the issue due to the search in the file taking so long?  Not sure.  Again thanks in advance for the assistance.

Here's an example of one of the files I'm parsing:

File: Ask/Illumina_ask.html AnswersQ&A Community Sign In Sign OutAdvanced SearchaskLogo * Everything * Images * News * Videos * Shopping * More * Maps * Less Explore Answers About --------------------- * Phone Number Belongs to * Free Cell Phone Number Search * Have Phone Number Need Name * Match a Phone Number to a Person * Greyhound Schedules and Fares * Justin Bieber * Phone Number Lookup * Free Unlisted Phone Number Search * Greyhound Bus Phone Number * Identify Phone Number * Cellular Phone Directory * Miley Cyrus More Answers Contact Us | Reach Illumina tech support and other key departments www.illumina.com/company/contact_us.ilmn Find email and phone contact information for customers seeking technical support or customer service, investors, the ... Contact Us ... Toll-free Phone Numbers ... Locations | Illumina commercial office locations www.illumina.com/company/contact-us/locations.ilmn 1.608.258.3080 outside North America 1.608.258.3088 ... 1.408.861.3610 phone ... Rm. 1103A, Bldg. H, Phoenix Place No. A5 Shuguangxili, Chaoyang District Illumina | Sequencing and array-based solutions for genetic research www.illumina.com/ Illumina's sequencing and array technologies fuel advancements in life science research, translational and consumer ... Contact Us · MyIllumina; Tools. Support - Illumina support.illumina.com/ Contact Us · MyIllumina; Tools. - BaseSpace · - DesignStudio · - Assay Design ... x Personalize your Illumina User Guides with the Custom Protocol Selector » ... About Us - Illumina www.illumina.com/company/about-us.ilmn SNP genotyping; Copy number variation; Genome sequencing; DNA ... and support throughout their relationship with us to maximize their scientific success. Suppliers | FAQs for current and prospective Illumina suppliers www.illumina.com/company/contact-us/suppliers.ilmn Bank Information: Bank of America Credit Inquiry Services ... Fax Number 415.343.9301. Trade Credit ... Phone: 408.245.5150 Ext. 155. VWR International, LLC Careers | Join us now and help make a difference - Illumina www.illumina.com/company/careers.ilmn Creativity helped build our company and continues to drive our growth. We have a relentless drive to make great products that can improve human health. We've ... Illumina, Inc. - San Diego, CA - Biotechnology | Facebook www.facebook.com/illuminainc ... 916 were here. Illumina is dedicated to advancing human health by unlocking the... ... Email or Phone, Password. Keep me .... Evan Eichler, PhD, joins us October 9th to discuss new mutations, genes & pathways in autism. Register here : ... Bats act as reservoirs for the Ebola virus and exhibit no symptoms of the disease. Working at Illumina | Glassdoor www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-Illumina-EI_IE11671.11,19.htm ... to work at Illumina. Salaries, reviews, and more - all posted by employees working at Illumina. ... About Us; Our Values; Giving Back; Why Illumina? Careers . Illumina Sequencing Technology | PerkinElmer www.perkinelmer.com/pages/020/genomic_analysis/illumina-sequencing-technology.xhtml Welcome Guest (Login/Register); USA (Change) .... Illumina is a leading provider of next-generation sequencing technology used for the analysis of genetic ... Explore More Answers About -------------------------- * Phone Number by Street Address * Celebrity Phone Numbers * Free Services to Lookup Cell Phone Numbers * Free Reverse Cell Phone Directory * I Have an Address but Need a Phone Number * Justin Bieber Phone Number for Real * Lookup Cell Phone Number with No Cost * Chris Brown 12345678910Next » Popular Q&A ----------- Q: What is the phone number for Illumina (sp) movie theater in Chape... ----------------------------------------------------------- A: 919-932-9000 for show times at the Read More » Source: www.chacha.com Q: How many active phone numbers are there in the US? ----------------------------------------------------- A: There are between 700M-800M assigned geographic telephone numbers. . Telecom service providers are the only entities that know how many active numbers they have... Read More » Source: www.quora.com Q: What is a phone number for US? --------------------------------- A: A phone number for the USA is 1 and then the area code of whatever state you are calling to, then the 7 digits that follow. Read More » Source: wiki.answers.com Q: How to Block a Phone Number on U.S. Cellular. ------------------------------------------------ A: 1. Dial "67" on your phone keypad. 2. Dial the number you want to call. 3. Press the "Send" or green phone button on your phone. Read More » Source: www.ehow.com Q: What is the approximate number of NFC enabled phones in the US? ---------------------------------------------------------- A: If you want to know specifically about nfc enable phones in US ,you can refer the following link .Hope it will help . . http://www.nfcrumors.com/. nfc-pho. Read More » Source: www.quora.com Mobile Site · About · Privacy · Terms · Careers · Ask Blog · Q&A · Mobile · Help ·  ****************************************

I now also have the problem that where I thought I just had to match Phone: I now need to match Phone "or" +1 "or "(" to return a number as the formats are all different.

So this line of my code:
    if (/Phone:\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
                $seen{$1} = 1;

needs to be something to accomplish that but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What's your input file format?

Comment: Provide us with sample input file so that it  will be clear.

Comment: *Please* show a sample of your input file. Also, please copy and paste it directly from one of your data source files if possible, rather than giving a "something like this" answer. I realise that personal details can be sensitive, but it's fine if you change, say, letters for different letters, and digits for different digits, as long as we can see the basic layout of the file. It's pretty much impossible to help without it.

Comment: Added example file above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace your `opendir` code segment with `glob`.

E.g.

```
for my $filename ( glob("$calls_dir/*.html") ) {
    open( my $filehandle, "<", $filename ) or die $!;
    while (<$filehandle>) {
        # do stuff
    }
}
```

Also - you're testing a pattern - to see if the pattern matches. Then - adding it to a hash. Then iterating each key of the hash. Why? This will be what causes your problem - because `$seen` accumulates entries each file you run through, so that `foreach` loop gets long. You can avoid this by declaring `%seen` within your `foreach` loop.

Otherwise - depending on your input file format, you probably want to do several pattern matches - one for each of address, phone number, etc. And the insert those into a hash, which you print outside the loop.

Comment: OK, I got the print function working by following your advise and putting declaring the $seen with the loop. Thanks for that.